# How to add custom button in outlook mail page and outlook calendar page using outlook add-ins manifest file?

Tags: outlook, office365, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

In outlook mail , mail read page and calendar page , i want to add a custom button using outlook add-ins manifest file

if i install outlook add-ins this button will be show on that places

Any extension point is there for custom button add , I want trigger some function in outlook add-ins after click that custom buttons

it is possible or not , The outlook mail support for add custom button using outlook add-ins

please suggest me

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Currently the feature you requested, is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our Tech Community Page. Please submit your request there and choose the appropriate label(s). Feature requests on [Tech Community](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform) are considered, when we go through our planning process.